# Garageband equivalent for Android?

Tags: music, audio-recording

I am thinking about getting an iPad 2 just so I can record music on Garageband, provided I find a way to input a USB mic. Anyways, I am admittedly a Google and Android fan and would much rather go that route and record music using an Android tablet where there would for sure be much more interoperability and maybe even a cloud sync service where I could collaborate with another musician 1,000 miles away in high quality, lossless form. Is there an app on Android or a web app that would support this kind of user experience on par with the user experience of Garageband?

I don't mind sticking with an iPad 2 for a year and then going back to Android when something more mature for Android comes out, but just thought I would ask here first.

Comment: Wait, you can use a USB mic with an iPad 2?

Comment: Supposedly there is an adapter (ipad camera connection kit) used in this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbNu6nlywCo

Comment: @ElijahLynn: Microphone Drivers will not be supported by the iPad, this is why USB devices haven't been made for the iPad. It's strictly for camera connectivity so you can move photos from your camera.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the best options would be:

- [uloops](http://uloops.net/umc/download.php)
- [caustic](http://www.appbrain.com/app/caustic/com.singlecellsoftware.caustic)
- [nanoloop](http://www.appbrain.com/app/nanoloop/com.nanoloop)

I haven't tried any of these on my tablet yet (advent vega). Let me know what you find

Comment: I just ordered a ASUS Transformer today and will try a few of these out.

Comment: Uloops is not really a recording app, you can make some repeated loops with it, but no recordings longer than the loop itself